# Emptying dropdown list on event not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have two dropdown menus and a linkbutton:

```
<form name="OptionForm" method="post">
  <p>
    <label for="ddlLocJobPhOpt" class="ui-accessible">Location Job Phase</label>
    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlLocJobPhOpt" data-mini="true"></asp:DropDownList>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="ddlFrmnOpt" class="ui-accessible">Foreman</label>
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlFrmnOpt" data-mini="true"></asp:DropDownList>
  </p>

  <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkSelectOptions" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right" runat="server" data-role="button" Class="custom-btn" data-inline="true" data-theme="c" data-transition="pop" UseSubmitBahavior="false" href="#" data-mini="true" OnClientClick="SelectOptions()">GO</asp:LinkButton>
</form>
```

When I click the linkbutton this function fires: SelectOptions()

I am trying to empty the second dropdown list when the button is clicked. But when I add:

```
var frmnDDL = $('#ddlFrmnOpt');
frmnDDL.html("");
```

or

```
var frmnDDL = $('#ddlFrmnOpt');
frmnDDL.empty();
```

and then renavigate to the OptionForm above the dropdown is still populated.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is your second post about the same issue...set up a fiddle and you will get a better response.

Comment: Did you try my suggestion on the other post? `$('#ddlFrmnOpt').find('option').remove();`

Comment: Yes, and I responded.

Comment: Ok cool, I didn't see the response...see my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @CaffGeek pointed out, your issue is the fact that ASP.NET uses the control's parent hierarchy to determine the rendered ID. You can continue using the Javascript and jQuery code you already have by using static IDs for your controls.

Try

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" ID="ddlLocJobPhOpt" data-mini="true"></asp:DropDownList>
```

and

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" ID="ddlFrmnOpt" data-mini="true"></asp:DropDownList>
```

As of .NET 4, adding

```
ClientIdMode="Static"
```

to any server side control tells ASP.NET to render the exact ID that you specified in your markup instead of rendering it based on its legacy rules.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Ah, that was introduced in 4.0?  I haven't done any WebForms programming since 3.5 and do not remember this. TIL

Comment: Yeah that was a new feature in 4.0

Answer (score 3):

I can almost guarantee that `frmnDDL.length` is 0.

.Net renames controls to something like `ctl00_MainContent_ddlFrmnOpt`

You have two options

1. you can change your jquery selector to the actual generated name (inspect the rendered html)
2. you can change your selector to do a partial match with something like `$("[id$=ddlFrmnOpt]")` or `$("select[id$=ddlFrmnOpt]")`

After that there are many ways to empty the select

```
frmnDDL.empty();
frmnDDL.children().remove();
frmnDDL.find('option').remove();
//etc, etc
```

Secondly, I'm confused by what you mean when you say "*and then renavigate to the OptionForm above the dropdown is still populated*."  If you are performing a postback, .net will reload the dropdown with it's data during it's page lifecycle. What you changed in the DOM was client side, and with the web being stateless, those changes aren't remembered between postbacks.

Answer (score 1):

Check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/74VHf/)

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $('#mySelect option').each(function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

Comment: This likely doesn't solve the problem, and using `.each` is not a good idea here. It's likely slower, and much harder to read than just `$('#mySelect option').remove();` or `$('#mySelect').children().remove();`

Comment: @CaffGeek I agree, though I suggested something similar to your suggestions in another post of his and it wasn't removing so I was not sure if it needed to cycle through each one to remove.